# ServerSocket.accept()

Tags: java

While i am running my program i have svrSocket.accept() method..My program is automatically getting terminated when it reaches to svrSocket.accept() method.
Please suggest what needs to be done.

Comment: Look at your console for errors and debug:)

Comment: My guess is that you've got an empty catch-block somewhere. Could you post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem? Posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be ideal.

Comment: Could you add some details or perhaps post a minimal example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: nothing is getting printed in console.

Comment: OK, but could you post some example *source code*? We're not psychic, so we can't debug your code from over here.

Comment: Initialised Server Scoket first                                                              private void listen()                                                { try{Socket sock= svrSocket.accept();}                           catch all exceptions.

Comment: yes i have initialised server socket

Comment: If nothing is printed, how do you know this is the line responsible? Have you tried a debugger to see what happens when you step over this line of code?

Comment: @Gaurav - please edit your question to add the relevant code there.  "catch all exceptions"?

Comment: If you show us your your code may be we can more you. I have the same problem and my server block on accept() method as some on say before the method accept() is a blooking call and if a client connect to your server his execution will continuous and for me the is what i have done: i have connecting a client to my server and evrithing run.

Answer (score 1):

Without example code or an error message for reference, according to the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29), your application may not be catching one of the following exceptions:

1. [IOException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)
2. [SecurityException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html)
3. [SocketTimeoutException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)
4. [IllegalBlockingModeException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/IllegalBlockingModeException.html)

Also, are you sure your application terminates? The only reason I ask is `accept()` blocks until a connection is made.

Comment: I have handled all the exceptions nothing is getting printed in console.

Comment: @Gaurav: Edit your question and include relevant code, otherwise everyone is left shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to provide before we can really help you.

1. Stacktraces for exceptions that accept() might be throwing.  If this is a simple console application look for those in the console of your IDE.  There is a separate window that it runs in and shows output like this.
2. Is the program truly terminating?  accept() is a blocking call and blocks forever until another process connects to it through the socket.  Have you tried running a client that connects to your server socket to see if it un blocks and continues to run?  If you have to click the stop button, if multiple run windows are open then your program is simply blocked on the accept() call and it's working as designed.